# Problem with the ST_Contains function in PostGIS on the comparison query

Tags: postgis

I want to check if a point is in a polygon or not with this query:

```
SELECT ST_Contains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res
```

Normally it must return true or false as the case but give the error:

```
Warning: pg_query (): Query failed: ERROR: function st_contains (unknown, unknown) is not unique LINE 1: SELECT ST_Contains ('0103000000010000001400000011FF156A9E3525 ... ^ HINT: cast in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ dashboard \ project_na_convertire_dxf \ new.php on line 116
```

What should I change in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell PostGreSQL those 2 values are geometries, because it doesn't know which type they are.  They could just as wel be texts.

You also missed a comma:

If you use:

```
SELECT ST_Contains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eometry, '0101000000B1DE9305D01C2541FB428F9E6C211741'::Geometry)
```

It gives *false* as the result.